# Как заменить двоеточие регулярным выражением в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка такая: `11:  oooops`, а к примеру нужна такая: `0- oooops`. Как это записать в регулярном выражении используя `String.replace()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно правило для вашей задачи, но если вопрос чисто про замену двоеточия, то вот так:

```js
var str   = '11:  oooops';
var regex = /\:/;
str = str.replace(regex, "-");
console.log(str);
```

Если исходя из самого вопроса, тогда как-то так:

```js
var str   = '11:  oooops';
var regex = /\d+\:/;
str = str.replace(regex, "0-");
console.log(str);
```